# setup.py bdist_egg is not putting files into the egg

Tags: python, setuptools, distribute

I have a confusing issue with python packaging

I have a setup.py that looks like this:

```
import os

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from ez_setup import use_setuptools
    use_setuptools()
    from setuptools import setup

config = {
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "3.0.15",
    "include_package_data": True,
    "scripts": ["something.py"],
    "entry_points": {},
    "zip_safe": False,
    }

setup(**config)
```

and a `MANIFEST.in` that looks like:

```
recursive-include mypackage *.*
recursive-exclude mypackage *.pyc .DS_Store
```

If I do `python setup.py sdist` a tar.gz file is written which contains all the right files

If I do `python setup.py bdist_egg` and then extract the contents of the egg using Stuffit Expander... I see a `scripts/something.py` file  but none of the `mypackage` source files.

However in the extracted egg `SOURCES.txt` the `mypackage` files are listed, so it seems like the minifest has been parsed, it just hasn't put them into the egg.

What am I misunderstanding/doing wrong?

Comment: This is basically the inverse of [Setuptools - shipping additional files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18144472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to list files to include in your binary distribution in the [`package_data` entry](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-package-data) to `setuptools.setup()`:

```
config = {
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "3.0.15",
    "include_package_data": True,
    "scripts": ["something.py"],
    "entry_points": {},
    "package_data": {'': ['*.ext1', '*.ext2']},
    "zip_safe": False,
    }
```

Comment: [The docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#including-data-files) say "`package_data`: Specify additional patterns to match files and directories that may or may not be matched by MANIFEST.in or found in source control." ...from that I understood that the above should not be necessary, it should use what is in `MANIFEST.in`

Comment: @Anentropic: but those files would not be installed from the source to the package on installation. There are 2 stages here: source packaging, and producing an installation on the target from the source. The MANIFEST controls the first stage, `package_data` the second.

Comment: @Anentropic: `bdist` aims to skip the first step packaging the result of the second step.

Comment: ok that explains it. in my case since I only need the python packages it looks like I could specify `packages: ['mypackage']` and not `package_data` ...I was trying to avoid the latter since I understood it would not automatically recurse through sub directories.  I see my mistake was trying to control everything from the manifest

Comment: perhaps I have failed at reading but I found the docs and the process unclear and confusing

Comment: @Anentropic: the process *is* unclear and confusing. Took me quite some time to grasp these concepts too. :-)